# PhoneGap show image downloaded with $.get

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to inject HTML code downloaded from URL into my page.
Here the JQuery code

```
$('#messageScreen').live('pageshow',  function() {  
    $('#messageContent').empty();  
    var url = testServerDirAdrs + 'message?message_id=' + selectedMessageId;  
    $.get(url,  
    function(data){  
            $('#messageContent').append(data).trigger('create');  
            },'html');  
});
```

It works fine, but when downloaded html contains images, they are not displayed. 
The image tag downloaded from the URL is:

```
<img src="/images/logos/muni_1_small.png" />
```

I guess the problem is with the path.

Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Thanks, Costa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below you can find 2 possible solutions:

> 1. The image can be downloaded from the **web** so the src could be like src="http://www.example.com/example/myexampleimg.png"
> 2. The image exists **locally** and the img tag's src must have relative path. For example if the html file in which the img tag will be appended is in the same path as your images folder then the path will be ./images/myexampleimg.png. In case your images path is one folder before  then the path will be ../images/myexampleimg.png etc

I hope this helps.